# Garbage collection increases heap size

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

We have a long running batch process that eventually will throw OutOfMemory error. It's a simple process that parses XML files and then transforms the data into a different format.  We tried visualvm to profile and monitor the process and noticed that whenever a garbage collection was performed, it released some memory but also increased the heap size, as illustrated in the picture. There seems to be a pattern here.  Could someone help to see whether this is actually memory leak? Any possible cause?

[image: picture]

Comment: Your lowest memory usage is constant while heap size is 350Mb out of 8Gb max. That is not how memory leaks look. If you are getting OutOfMemory that is because of something else like PermGen exhaustion.

Comment: @Talijanac Picture show that it took 1 hour to increase from 200 MB to 350 MB, so extrapolate another 55 hours, and memory will run full. Question did say "long running batch process", without specifying how long that is.

Comment: My guess is that the system is running a lot of incremental GCs, until it cannot find any more objects to release, then it runs a full GC, allocating more memory from the OS. Seems you system is generating a lot of short-lived objects, but also retaining long-lived objects (potential memory leak).

Comment: Thanks Tilijanac and Andreas.  We are using Spring Batch with partitioning (fixed number of threads).  Each thread at a given time reads and parses one xml (could be big) and then transforms/outputs the data as a file.  If the process runs more than two days, it runs out of memory.  I am guessing there's memory leak somewhere since I expect each thread should be using constant like memory.  :(

Comment: @Andreas
There is literally no memory exhaustion in this picture. Each time full GC is triggered memory allocation drops to the about 60-70 mb of usage (lowest points on graph). Because lowest points do not increase after full GC there is no memory exhaustion and that is that. Heap allocation does increase each time by about 20% but this is just GC algorithm optimizing performance because it can. As allocated memory (350 mb) is much smaller than max allowed (8gb) heap size heap size is increased in order to postpone successive full GCs.

Comment: @Tina There are multiple memory pools in JVM and improper sizing of any of those pools will trigger OutOfMemory error. PermGen exhaustion, native heap exhaustion, not having enough ram in computer.. Whatever it is it isn't present in question asked. You should enable heap dumps on OOM and analyze those dumps when they happen. See: https://plumbr.io/blog/memory-leaks/solving-outofmemoryerror-dump-is-not-a-waste